# Diseño de negocio

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy diseñando un negocio que trata de la venta de ropa en el cual tengo que mostrar un stock de la ropa como Modelo(pantalón, short, polo), Color, Talla y Cantidad.

Tengo las siguientes entidades de negocio:

- Producto
- Talla
- Colores
- ProductoTalla: Esta entidad me permite una relación **many to many** con Producto
- ProductoColor: Esta entidad me permite una relación **many to many** con Producto

Hasta ahi ya tengo definido que un producto tiene ciertas tallas y ciertos colores.

---

Ahora cuando haga el ingreso a Almacén tengo que registrar por modelo, talla, color y cantidad ejemplo: pantalón Pioner, talla 30, color azul, cantidad 15 ......

Tengo creada las siguiente entidades de negocio:

- Almacén
- DetalleAlmacen: En el cual esta relacionado con Almacén, Talla, Color.

Cree esta entidad por que así puedo al momento de registrar un ingreso a Almacén: pantalón Pioner, talla 30, color azul, cantidad 15 ...

1. ¿Que les parece la entidad DetalleAlmacen y sus relaciones con Talla
   y Color?
2. ¿Necesito una entidad Inventario que este relacionado a Almacén para
   poder saber el stock?
3. ¿Almacén e Inventario registran entradas y salidas?

Pero Almacén registra entradas de ingreso a Almacén de una supuesta compra a Proveedores y registra egreso a otros almacenes si es un almacén principal como también puede ser un único almacén.

Inventario registra los egreso por cada venta.

¿Cual es la responsabilidad de la entidad Almacén e Inventario?

[image: Diseño de negocio]

Comment: Siempre los DER o UML llevan a discucion, porque no hay una forma correcta de hacerlo. es segun el punto de vista del diseñador/programador. Por eso me parece que mas que una pregunta seria un tema para debatir. Según mi punto de vista, deberías tener una tabla que contenga "ProdcutoCompleto"  ProdCompletoID,ProductoID,ColorID,TallaID, cantidad. Asi pueden cargar la cantidad de este producto y después descontarlo. y en el DetalleAlmacen podrías guardar el ProdCompletoID y ahorrarte los demás id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**>>¿Que les parece la entidad DetalleAlmacen y sus relaciones con Talla y Color?**

es correcta la entidad, pero si por medio de esta relacionas producto, talla y color para que tienes las tablas ProductoTalla y ProductoColor ?

Desde mi punto de vista no se necesitan estas relaciones si es por medio de `DetalleAlmacen` que unes los 3 conceptos

`DetalleAlmacen` deberia tener una clave triple entre los id de producto, talla y color y seria esta tabla la unica que los relaciona.

Aqui puede haber otra alternativa como ser

```
ProductoEspecificacion (tabla)
EspeciaificacionId  PK
ProductoId FK
TallaId FK
ColorId  FK
```

por supuesto deberias definir un Indice UNIQUE que no permita duplicados entre los campos ProductoId, TallaId y ColorId

entonces el detalle del almacen quedaria

```
DetalleAlamacen (tabla)
AlmacenId  PK
EspeciaificacionId PK
Cantidad
```

Como veras hay varias formas de modelar lo que planteas, pero creo que un concepto de Producto Especializacion (puede usar este nombre u otro que el negocio defina) o algo por ese lado seria util

**>>¿Necesito una entidad Inventario que este relacionado a Almacén para poder saber el stock?**

No, en este caso el DetalleAlmacen cumple esa funciona, solo le has cambiado el nombre

**>>¿Almacén e Inventario registran entradas y salidas?**

En tu caso seria solo el detalle del almacen es quien llevaria las operaciones de stock de los productos

Comment: Leandro con la solución que me das se mantinen las entidades ProductoTalla y ProductoColor?

Comment: Si vas a definir la entidad de "Especificacion" no haria falta ya que esta entidad une las tres (Producto, Talle y color), recuerda lo que mencione del UNIQUE entre estos 3 campos, ya que seria algo complicado si defines claves compuestas